# Getting an Alert from one Activity to show as a Toast in another Activity in Android app

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-toast

I'm wondering if this is possible.

I have a guessing game that shows an alert when they either get it wrong or right at the end of the game.  What I want to know is, can an alert be shown as a toast in another activity?

This is one of the alerts:

```
pressMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
           boolean correct = false;
           final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Task3Activity.this);
           alert.setTitle("Unlucky");
           alert.setCancelable(false);
           alert.setMessage("You have guessed incorrectly three times. " +
                   "The answer was " + ranNum + ". " + "Would you like to play again?")
```

My game has a button that returns the user to another activity from where they came to play the game.  The code for this is below:

```
public class GameCentral extends AppCompatActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_central_layout);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.commonmenus, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.guessingGame)
    {

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Guessing Game option is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Task3Activity.class));
    }
    else if (id ==R.id.placeOne) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Game Placeholder One option is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (id ==R.id.placeTwo) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Game Placeholder Two option is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (id ==R.id.placeThree) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Game Placeholder Three option is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

The toasts that reside in here are just for the menu options from the action bar.

I'm not sure how I would even start to make the alert in one activity show as a toast in another activity once an exit button had been pressed.

Thanks

Comment: An AlertDialog is much different than a Toast

Comment: And I don't what you mean "show Toast in another Activity" because a Toast displays on top of everything, not the current Activity.

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess what I want is the result of the game to show as a toast when the user presses the button to come out of the game so I guess it doesn't need to go from one activity to another. Thanks for that. It's clarified it a bit for me